# Django Graphene/GraphQL best design for model field-level permissions

Tags: django, graphene-django

I am using Django as back-end with graphene-django serving the front-end. I am new to both django and graphene so I am not sure what is the best approach to achieve field-level permissions with no code repetition in this set-up. For example, if my model is:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   field1 = models.CharField()
   field2 = models.CharField()
```

I want to be able to specify that user1 can read field1 but *not* field2; when the user1 queries GraphQL for all MyModels it would be only allow to retrieve field1 from rows (nodes) and not field2.

I did a bit of research and found 2 possible alternative solutions but I fear they may not be in the spirit of Django framework and/or conflicting with each other and there may be a better way to achieve this in Django. Ultimately I don't want to be repeating the permissions code in multiple parts of the Django and Graphene back-end so want this to be centralised at the lowest possible level, ideally at the Django model. I need to be able to control full CRUD per field depending on user_id and maybe even have some additional logic. The options I found were:

1. overriding get_node resolver in graphene-django DjangoObjectType to check for permissions there. Personally I see this as a very bad and last-resort solution as the checks are done only on graphql query/mutation layer and not elsewhere in Django. I could easily write a Django form or view that would not benefit from the permission check unless this is coded again in that form/view.
2. I could extend the Django model to perform arbitrary per-field checks and this seems the right level where to enforce permission checks but ideally I would prefer to use built-in features or a 'popular' library for this type of stuff. I tried searching for a library but I couldn't find anything that is even remotely production ready or gaining any traction - which leads me to the consider that there may be a better approach to address this problem. [Django-field-permissions](https://github.com/tiliv/django-field-permissions) package seemed on the right path though.

I was wondering if anyone has a view on the best approach to solving this problem that fits Django and Graphene frameworks and without repeating the permissions code everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to find a stable/popular package for this, as it's not a design that a database can support well.

You cannot link (Foreign Key) a field and a table, you can only link two tables using a field. Therefore, any work to determine whether a row in a table has access to a field in another table, will be costly and error prone.

The best you could do, is to write a service layer that sits in between a resolver and a model that nullifies fields a user has no access to. You pass it the user (`info.context.user`) and a model, and it does a separate query to a field permissions model, fetches the record and nullifies each field according to permissions.

This inherently means each field needs to be nullable in order to support the permissions, complicating the frontend - it's a lot of work...

A better approach if your business logic allows it, is to group those fields into models, that can then be tied to "roles" or groups. So if this were medical data in  a hospital:

```
- name  ----- \
- address     | -> Person model => all personnel, except custodial
- birth date -/
- medication -------\
- patient history   | => PatientStatus model => all medically trained personnel
- current physician /
- ...
```

That way you use standard built-in permissions to deny access to entire tables (as illustrated above) and object level permissions ([Guardian](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html), [Authority](https://github.com/jazzband/django-authority)) to deny access to all but the current physician for the really classified things.

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thanks - this is really helpful and echoes my thinking! It feels splitting the object based on permissions is the easiest way to go